# black screen shows when I turn on my laptop after inserting my SSD where ubuntu 18.04 is installed

Tags: boot, 18.04, ssd, bios

I have installed ubuntu on my SSD (Apacher 256GB) using another laptop by connecting it as an external hard disk.
After completing the installation, It worked fine on that laptop. But when I inserted that SSD on another laptop as the main disk, ubuntu did not start. The SSD showed a blank screen when I turn on my laptop.
What do I need to do to start ubuntu working on my computer as main disk?

Comment: Good chance the video driver is the issue.

Comment: Is it logical to open up ubuntu? I thought It would work fine but it did not @David

Comment: The video card on both computers is the exact same make and model and has the same chip sets?

Comment: No. The laptop I used to boot SSD externally is Dell inspiron 15 3501, core i7 processor.
The laptop where I am inserting SSD is Asus X541UA, core i5 processor.

Comment: And there maybe other issue at play. By default the Ubuntu installer only installs Grub in the internal drive's ESP (EFI System Partition) so it works on the computer it was installed but not others. Is there any reason why you didn't installed Ubuntu directly in the target machine?

Comment: I asked about the video card you told me everything but.

Comment: The graphics is important here of couse. The Dell one can have a dGPU Nvidia but the Asus only an iGPU Intel. It shouldn't be a problem, theoretically, because the original installation should contain as well the open-source drivers for Intel Graphics but other issues may arise. Again, why not install directly?

Comment: actually, I did not get your question. Did you mean graphics card? @David

Comment: yes the most common but not the only reason for a black screen.

Comment: If I install directly then It does not finish installing. Before starting the installation It says - "ACPI region does not cover...". Sometimes It does not finish copying files, sometimes the installer gets hanged, sometimes while creating partitions the installer crashes. But the same bootable USB worked fine for another laptop while installing ubuntu. Another thing I want to share is ubuntu was installed fine during dual boot with windows 10. But when I tried to install  only ubuntu on the SSD ubuntu does not get installed. @ChanganAuto

Comment: No, graphics cards are different. 
Now It says "insert a bootable media" when I select my ssd during setup @David

Comment: Before anything else update uEFI. The problems you describe may oir may not be solved or attenuated with a newer firmware. Also make sure you're booting in uEFI mode and use "erase and install" to have the correct partitioning done automatically.

Comment: And to be clear: If it can't install correctly for whatever reason, it's highly unlikely it boots an installation made elsewhere. Keep in mind the drive can be good but either the connector and/or the controller in the old Asus can be broken somehow.